# Failed to download GoogleMaps by CocoaPods in China

Tags: ios, google-maps

I've tried CocoaPods to import GoogleMaps to my project in China. But I failed because of network shielding like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZXQP.jpg)

I accesse blocked sites then try it again but failed either.
Now I just don't know how to work it and I have no idea to deal with.

Comment: It might be illegal in China so, please, check that first, but you can use a VPN to go around the "Great Firewall" (there's a bunch of them available, the one I use is https://www.getcloak.com). Overall, Google has rather strained relationships with Chinese government, if you are looking for something that should be useful in China, you may want to consider another provider (Baidu, Apple, https://www.mapbox.com). Good luck!

Comment: the "Great Firewall" ... It's the first time I have ever heard, hahaha, so funny

Answer (score 0):

Try to open a 'VPN', And try again.